# Character processing and character iteration

Tags: c

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{

int i, j, tree_Size, spaces, total_Spaces, x;
char tree_Characters;

printf("Enter characters to use --> ");
 scanf("%c", &tree_Characters);
printf("Enter size of tree --> ");
 scanf("%d", &tree_Size);

   //For handling top part of tree
   for (i = 0; i <= tree_Size; i++) {
      printf("\n");
      total_Spaces = tree_Size - i;

        //Determine spaces before each number for pyramid
      for (spaces = 1; spaces <= total_Spaces; spaces++) 
         printf(" ");

      //Make first line always one number
      for (j = -1; j < i; j++)
         if (j <= -1)
            printf("%c", tree_Characters);
         else if (j > -1)
            printf("%c%c", tree_Characters, tree_Characters);
   } 

   //For handling stem and base of tree
   for (i = 0; i <= tree_Size; i++) {

      //if handling stem
      if (i < tree_Size) {
         printf("\n");  
         for (spaces = 1; spaces <= tree_Size; spaces++)
            printf(" ");
         printf("%c", tree_Characters);
      }

      //else if handling base

      else if (i == tree_Size) {
         printf("\n");

         for (x = 0; x <= tree_Size * 2; x++) {
            printf("%c", tree_Characters);
         }
      }
   }

printf("\n");

}
```

[Here is the output it produces so far](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20930447/screenshots/Screenshot-9.png)
[Here is a thread I made on reddit for better understanding (comments)](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/fy094/c_character_processing_and_iteration_need_help_d/)

The goal of the assignment is for it to look like this:

```
*** Print a Tree ***

Enter characters to use ---   *|=+
Enter size of tree      ---   4

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
    |
    |
    |
    |
====+====
```

What I don't understand is how to process characters.  The teacher was mentioning putting characters into some buffer and then clearing it etc, I have no idea. Can anyone help? I have to use scanf, can't convert anything to strings or use anything advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `tree_Characters` a array (`char tree_Characters[5]` for a five element array, which will hold your four tree chars and a nul terminator), and change the first scanf.

```
scanf("%4s%*[^\n]",tree_Characters);
//      vv\_____/  ^-- array will decay to char*
//      ||   \-- discard the rest of the line
//      ||         ("*" indicates discard, "[^\n]" matches everything but '\n')
//      |\-- string (non-whitespace characters only)
//      \-- at most four characters scanned
```

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf for more information.

Edit: You will of course have to change the rest of the program to select the appropriate characters for each tree element. (See [@eznme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206500/character-processing-and-character-iteration/5206623#5206623).)

#### Edit: No-array Version:

```
char tree_leaf,tree_stem,tree_ground,tree_root;
scanf("%c%c%c%c%*[^\n]",&tree_leaf,&tree_stem,&tree_ground,&tree_root);
```

This will react badly to too-short input lines.

Comment: Cannot use arrays, or pointers or anything like that. This assignment was specifically designed to input characters and then put them into a junk variable to use the next available character per tree part. Thanks though.

Comment: That is ... incredibly stupid (on the teachers part), but should be easy to work around.

Comment: It's not. He teaches us one thing at a time then gives us a lab/assignment that will let us use that to get an understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Enter characters to use --> *|=+
    Enter size of tree --> 4

        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
        |
        |
        |
        |
    ====+====
```

Here's the modified source, the lines i changed i marked with // **:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()

    {

    int i, j, tree_Size, spaces, total_Spaces, x;
    char tree_Characters[4]; //**

    printf("Enter characters to use --> ");
     scanf("%s", tree_Characters);          // **
    printf("Enter size of tree --> ");
     scanf("%d", &tree_Size);

       //For handling top part of tree
       for (i = 0; i <= tree_Size; i++) {
          printf("\n");
          total_Spaces = tree_Size - i;

            //Determine spaces before each number for pyramid
          for (spaces = 1; spaces <= total_Spaces; spaces++) 
             printf(" ");

          //Make first line always one number
          for (j = -1; j < i; j++)
             if (j <= -1)
                printf("%c", tree_Characters[0]); // **
             else if (j > -1)
                printf("%c%c", tree_Characters[0], tree_Characters[0]); // **
       } 

       //For handling stem and base of tree
       for (i = 0; i <= tree_Size; i++) {

          //if handling stem
          if (i < tree_Size) {
             printf("\n");  
             for (spaces = 1; spaces <= tree_Size; spaces++)
                printf(" ");
             printf("%c", tree_Characters[1]); // **
          }

          //else if handling base

          else if (i == tree_Size) {
             printf("\n");

             for (x = 0; x < tree_Size; x++) { // **
                printf("%c", tree_Characters[2]); // **
             }
             printf("%c", tree_Characters[3]); // **
              for (x = 0; x < tree_Size; x++) { // **
                printf("%c", tree_Characters[2]); // **
             }
          }
       }

    printf("\n");

    getch();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that solution, unfortunately it cannot be used as we cannot use strings.

Comment: I think the instruction to not use strings was meant to keep you away from the c++ string-class. What i use in this code is all part of standard C.

Comment: We cannot use anything related to strings.

Comment: Memory is related to strings. (What I use here is only memory). Good luck! :-)